# How does the wave function of a particle behave in this experimental setup?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I'm sorry that the title isn't very clear. This really requires some diagrams.

I was looking at the OCW course on quantum mechanics, where the lecturer described electrons as having two binary (imaginary / substitute) properties: Color and Hardness. A particle can be either black or white, and Hard or Soft. He continues to describe how uncertainty dictates that if we measure hardness, send the beam of all soft electrons to be measured for colour, and subsequently let the electrons be measured for hardness again, they will now have lost their previous hardness information and will be 50/50 hard/soft.

In this lecture, he draws the following diagram:

[image]

Here he sends white particles into an apparatus, which measures hardness, uses mirrors to re-combine the beams and measures colour again. Although the intuitive answer would be that colour information would be lost by this process; it is in fact false. Instead, when we measure the colour at the end, we find that 100% of the particles are still white.

This can be simply explained by the fact that the wave function of the particle travels along both legs simultaneously, arriving at the mirror at the same time, which will remove information about which route it took, and then when the colour measurement happens, it is as if the hardness never got measured.

My question is this:

> What happens if we change the length of these legs such that the hard
> particles take one second to arrive at the colour box, and soft
> particles take 2 seconds to arrive at the same box.

Since we can also measure the time it took to arrive at the colour box, we would be able to determine whether the particle has been measured as hard or soft. Does that mean that this act of temporally splitting the beams will lose colour information and the result would be 50/50 once more?

If not, what *is* happening here?

Comment: Assuming they move at a constant speed is an idealisation.

Comment: Since this is a thought experiment, we could put the apparatus in space and make the soft leg 10^6 times as long as the hard leg. Are you saying that no matter the difference, somehow the parts of the wave function will arrive at the combining mirror at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if one route takes one second and the other two seconds then the results for color will be 50-50.

You can think about this scenario in terms of preserving information about which path the particle took, and therefore information about its hardness. But another, and easier, at least for me, way to conceptualize what's going on is this:

In the original scenario, the reason the final measurement for color always produced white was because the two paths interfered with each other. But in order to interfere with each other they have to be "at the same place at the same time".

So if the two paths arrive at the final detector at different times, they cannot interfere.